# How to retrieve content from a website with VS 11

Tags: c#

I am trying this in Visual Studio 11 in Windows 8. As I see I can't use `WebClient` to do this, so I tried using `HttpClient`:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.Get("http://google.com");
var result = XDocument.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsString());
```

My problem is that I always get result to be null. In response I get a status code 200 (OK) but I can't see the content.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use `WebClient`?

Comment: Also, Google.com is not valid XML.

Comment: @SLaks: I include Syste,.Net but it doesn't find WebClient and it doesn't work with any website, I am trying to get the xml from a page

Comment: You'd better use GetAsync() in Metro apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most webpages are not valid XML.

You should use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.